# Flutter cannot find the file required for the emulator

Tags: visual-studio-code, arp, nt

Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Hasan\OneDrive\Masa�st�\ilkders\laaaa\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
> Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU?LD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with your file path that your Flutter project is under. I see just in your question there are 2 of the replacement characters (�). This means that you have some character that is not ASCII in your file path which Flutter doesn't support. Either rename your directory without these characters or move your project to a directory that doesn't have these characters.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so please click the green check mark to set as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error message literally tells you what you need to fix.

Get rid of the non-ASCII characters in the path.